# Lambda Function Substitute in Visual Studio 2005 -- Boost Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lambda

The last line below will not compile in Visual Studio 2005:

```
std::deque<int> q;
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mu;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> locker(mu);
cond.wait(locker, [](){ return !q.empty();} );  // Unlock mu and wait to be notified
```

I think it's a lambda Expression and I suspect that the Visual Studio 2005 compiler does not support the syntax...C++11?  Is there anyway that I can fix this besides changing my compiler?

Here is the class declaration from boost:

```
class condition_variable:
    private detail::basic_condition_variable
{
public:
    BOOST_THREAD_NO_COPYABLE(condition_variable)
    condition_variable()
    {}

    using detail::basic_condition_variable::notify_one;
    using detail::basic_condition_variable::notify_all;

    void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& m)
    {
        do_wait(m,detail::timeout::sentinel());
    }

    template<typename predicate_type>
    void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& m,predicate_type pred)
    {
        while(!pred()) wait(m);
    }
```

...

Compiler Output:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '['
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Comment: Boost has lambdas with Boost.Lambda and Boost.Phoenix.

Comment: @chris: But doesn't the compiler have to support the syntax?  If not, what Boost headers should I include to compile the above code?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's the beauty of it. Boost does some pretty awesome things with just C++03. Anyway, go have a look at the documentation (and tutorial). That includes the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UntilEmpty
{
public:
    UntilEmpty(std::deque<int>& t) : q(t) {}

    bool operator() () { return !q.empty(); }

private:
    std::deque<int>& q;
};
```

Then to use simply:

```
UntilEmpty until_empty(q);
cond.wait(locker, until_empty);
```

By the way, UntilEmpty is commonly referred to as a functor.

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally omitted the declaration of the queue.  I edited my original question to add it.

Comment: Your solution above works.  Still interested in adding lambda support via Chris's suggestion above, but it's more complicated than simply adding the boost headers: #include "boost\lambda\lambda.hpp" and
#include "boost\phoenix\phoenix.hpp".  I'll check out the lambda tutorial as he suggested.